# What is the default DPI for NSAttributedString's initWithHTML?

Tags: html, cocoa, nsattributedstring, dpi

I'm using NSAttributedString's -initWithHTML:documentAttributes: method to create an attributed string from HTML-Code. The HTML-Code I try to convert may contain font sizes specified in Millimeters. The resulting attributed string contains a font size in points.
I would like to know the default DPI to scale the text to match my target DPI.

In my tests, it seems that the method uses ~96 DPI.

```
    NSString *html = @"<html><span style='font-size:10mm'>example</span></html>";
    NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data documentAttributes:nil];

    NSFont *font = [string attribute:NSFontAttributeName atIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL];

    CGFloat pointSize = [font pointSize];

    CGFloat defaultDPI = pointSize / 10.0 * 25.4; // (1 mm == 25.4 inch)

    NSLog(@"default DPI: %f.", defaultDPI); // returns 96.520000
```

However, I can't find documentation for this number and I am afraid that it may change in the future. Therefore, my questions:

Is there a better way to get the default DPI? Is there perhaps a way to specify the DPI before the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

The DPI will differ depending on the display device. Typical values are 72dpi on a monitor and 96 dpi in the browser (or at least it pretends to be 96dpi, even if ultimate display device is not capable). This is going to vary on a Mac though with Retina screens and so on.

If you are displaying this in a browser like context I would stick with the standard 96dpi assumption and trust the font-size directive.